# JPA entities, servicelayer and repositories: Am i doing this right?

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink

im not really sure, if i'm doing it right in my service/persistence layer.
In my case i have four entities: User, Category, Investment and Investmentrepeat:

### User:

```
public class User implements Identifiable, Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Investment> investmentList;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_investment", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "investment") })
private List<Investment> publicInvestmentList;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Category> categoryList;

...
}
```

### Category:

```
public class Category implements Identifiable, Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)")
@NotNull
private User owner;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Investment> investmentList;

...
}
```

### Investment:

```
public class Investment implements Identifiable, Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner")
@NotNull
private User owner;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "publicInvestmentList")
private List<User> publicUserList;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "category")
@NotNull
private Category category;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "investmentrepeat")
@NotNull
private InvestmentRepeat investmentRepeat;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "owninginvestmentrepeat", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20)")
private InvestmentRepeat owningInvestmentRepeat;

...
}
```

### Investmentrepeat:

```
public class InvestmentRepeat implements Identifiable, Serializable {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "investmentRepeat", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Investment> investmentList;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "owningInvestmentRepeat", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotNull
private Investment parentInvestment;

...
}
```

For each entity there exists a stateless service class e.g. UserService, CategoryService.

My first question is, if my function to create a new category for a user is right and do i need to update the user entity after persisting the category?

### CategoryService:

```
 public Category createWithReferences(String categoryTitle, User owner,
        boolean deleteable) throws ServiceException,
        EntityPersistenceException {
    if (owner == null) {
        throw new ServiceException(getMessageService()
                .getMessageFromBundle("error.user_not_found_by_id"));
    }
    if (categoryTitle == null || categoryTitle.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ServiceException(getMessageService()
                .getMessageFromBundle("error.category.no_title"));
    }

    Category newCategory = new Category(categoryTitle, owner, deleteable);
    owner.addCategorie(newCategory);

    newCategory = this.repository.create(newCategory);
    userService.update(owner);

    return newCategory;
}
```

### BaseEntityRepository implements the CRUD Operations of the entities:

```
@Override
public T create(T obj) throws EntityPersistenceException {
    EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw new EntityPersistenceException(
                "Could not create Object of Instance: "
                        + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName()
                        + "; ErrorMessage: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return obj;
}

@Override
public T update(T obj) throws EntityPersistenceException {
    EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        obj = this.getEntityManager().merge(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw new EntityPersistenceException(
                "Could not update Object of Instance: "
                        + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName()
                        + "; ErrorMessage: " + e.getMessage() + "; ID: "
                        + obj.getId());
    }
    return obj;
}

@Override
public void delete(T obj) throws EntityPersistenceException {
    EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    try {
        if (obj != null) {
            long id = 0;
            if (obj instanceof Identifiable) {
                id = ((Identifiable) obj).getId();
                T entity = getEntityManager().find(getType(), id);
                //entity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
                getEntityManager().remove(entity);
                tx.commit();
            }
        }
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw new EntityPersistenceException(
                "Could not delete Object of Instance: "
                        + obj.getClass().getCanonicalName()
                        + "; ErrorMessage: " + e.getMessage() + "; ID: "
                        + obj.getId());
    }
}
```

When i don't update the user after creating the entity, the user doesn't contains the new category when i refresh him by em.find(...), but the new category is created in the database.

Another point is, when im persisting an new investment with an investmentrepeat, then in the db-table investmentrepeat the id of the parentinvestment is everytime 0 or when i remove the @NotNull annotation then the id is null. And is it right how i add an investment to the category? Here is the function where i create an new investment:

### InvestmentService:

```
public Investment createWithReferences(User owner, String description,
        double amount, Date investDate, Category category,
        InvestmentRepeat investmentRepeat, boolean isParentInvestment)
        throws ServiceException, EntityPersistenceException {
    if (owner == null) {
        throw new ServiceException(getMessageService()
                .getMessageFromBundle("error.user_not_found_by_id"));
    }
    if (category == null) {
        throw new ServiceException(getMessageService()
                .getMessageFromBundle("error.category_is_null"));
    }
    if (investmentRepeat == null) {
        throw new ServiceException(getMessageService()
                .getMessageFromBundle("error.investmenterepeat_is_null"));
    }

    // Create investment
    Investment newInvestment = new Investment(investDate,
            new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC), amount, description,
            owner, category, investmentRepeat);
    // add Investment to investmentRepeat and Category
    investmentRepeat.getInvestmentList().add(newInvestment);

    if (isParentInvestment) {
        investmentRepeat.setParentInvestment(newInvestment);
        newInvestment.setOwningInvestmentRepeat(investmentRepeat);
    }

    owner.findCategory(category).addInvestment(newInvestment);
    owner.addInvestment(newInvestment);

    // create investment
    newInvestment = this.create(newInvestment);

    // update Owner
    userService.update(owner);

    return newInvestment;
}
```

I hope somebody can tell me which mistakes i'm doing and where my knowledge about jpa is wrong :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a category to a user is to do the following.

1. Make sure your user has the category list otherwise it will replace all of the categories with only your latest one
2. Add the new category created to the list
3. Update the user entity since you have cascade on the relation the category will get persisted and the match will be made with the user.

Will look at the second question now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! you mean i should comment the `newCategory = this.create(newCategory)`. But when i do this, the newly created category in the categorylist of the user has the id = null. And when im now adding a second new category to the list and update the user, then there are two categories with the id = null and the ids in the Database category-table changes.

Comment: You should do like this: `Category newCategory = new Category(categoryTitle, owner, deleteable);
    owner.addCategorie(newCategory);
    userService.update(owner);`

Comment: When i doing this, then e.g. owner.getCategorList().get(0).getId() is null. Because the merge operation on the category will be made. The newCategory is in the Database, but has an null id in the list of the owner, until i refreh the owner :/